# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined Angular

Tags: angular

I am bringing information from my backend, it is displayed satisfactorily on my website. But I get the errors "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')" and "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')".

```
product!: IResponseProduct;
imagesProducts: any[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    let { id } = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.params;
    this._productSrv.getProduct(id).subscribe((response) => {this.product = response;});
    this._productSrv.listImagenByIdProduct(id).subscribe((response) => (this.imagesProducts = response));
}
```

The image and name are displayed on the web

```
<div class="card img-big-wrap" style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="#"><img [src]="imagesProducts[0].url" /></a>
    <h3 class="title">{{product.name}}</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all about the **Angular lifecycle hooks**.

In the template you are accessing **imagesProducts** and **product** variables. However you are not defining them in **ngOnInit** hook as it looks like, but sometimes later (because obviously this._productSrv.getProduct(id) and this._productSrv.listImagenByIdProduct(id) are async operations).

So there are several solutions to this, one of the easiest is to use optional chaining operator.

```html
<div class="card img-big-wrap" style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="#"><img [src]="imagesProducts[0]?.url" /></a>
    <h3 class="title">{{product?.name}}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case, the compiler fails: {{**product? .price** / 12 | number: '1.0-2'}} Object is possibly 'undefined'

Comment: There are several ways to resolve this. One of them is like to add an initial value for the pipe. For example {{product?.price || 0)/12 | number: '1.0-2'}} Another way would be not to display product at all if doest not exist. <h3 *ngIf="product" class="title">{{product.price / 12 | number: '1.0-2'}} </h3> (In that way you dont need optional chaining ofc)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked for me:
Using the *ngIf directive

```
<div class="card img-big-wrap" style="text-align: center;">
    <a routerLink="#"><img [src]="imagesProducts[0].url" /></a>
    <h3 class="title" *ngIf="product">{{product.name}}</h3>
</div>
```

The error goes away.